# What are the first digits of the number $(\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3})^{2004}$ before and after the decimal point of its decimal representation?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

How can i find the first three digits of the number $(\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3})^{2004}$ before and after the decimal point of its decimal representation?

Comment: How many do you need?

Comment: Hint: Use binomial theorem and focus only on the terms you need.

Answer (score 7):

Let $$\alpha = (\sqrt 2+\sqrt 3)^2\quad \&\quad \overline {\alpha}=(\sqrt 2-\sqrt 3)^2$$

We are, of course, interested in $\alpha^{1002}$.

We remark that the minimal polynomial for $\alpha$ is $x^2-10x+1$  so $a_n=\alpha^n+\overline {\alpha}^n$ satisfies the recursion $$a_n=10a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}\quad a_0=2\quad a_1=10$$

It follows that $a_n$ is an integer for all $n\in \mathbb N$.  We remark that $\overline {\alpha}^n$ is effectively $0$ for large $n$ but that it is always positive.

Studying the recursion $\pmod {10}$  we get $$a_n\equiv -a_{n-2}\pmod {10}$$ from which we immediately see that $a_n\equiv \{2,0,8,0\}\pmod {10}$ periodically.   Since $1002$ is $2 \pmod 4$ we see that the units place of the integer $a_{1002}$ is $8$.

Since $\overline {\alpha}^{1002}$ is a very small positive number we see that for $\alpha^{1002}$ the entry to the left of the decimal must be $7$ and the entry to right after the decimal must be $9$.

Sanity check:  The same reasoning would apply to, say, $(\sqrt 2+\sqrt 3)^{20}=\alpha^{10}$ since $10\equiv 2 \pmod 4$. Indeed, brute force shows that $$(\sqrt 2+\sqrt 3)^{20}=903450249\underline{\color{red}{7}.\color{red}9}999999998$$